# Ruby sysread IO much too slow

Tags: ruby, linux, api, io

I have a command like this where `input` is a string that receives the input:

```
STDIN.sysread(1000,input)
```

If it reads more than 100 characters it takes more than 0.1 seconds.

I tried it with alternatives such as `partialread` and nonblocking reading and `read`, but I didn't find a faster alternative so far.

Do you know any faster possibility to simply read this?

---

```
t=Time.now
STDIN.sysread(1000,input)
stdin_time=Time.now-t
```

`stdin_time` is bigger than 0.1 `if input.length > 100`

I read mouse movements from terminal within X-Window.

Does `sysread` wait for more input than available before it finishes execution?

---

Even that doesn't work:

```
t=Time.now
Thread.new{
    input=STDIN.sysread(1000)
}.join(0.001)
stdin_time=Time.now-t
```

`stdin_time` is still >0.01, just as before.

---

The 0.01 seconds are visible on the screen when moving the mouse. It's not only a theoretical number problem, but it's visible. The problem is definitely there.

Comment: Either your time keeping is way too inaccurate or you are using a blocking writer which can't keep up with your reading. Remember: both writing to and reading from a file can be blocking.

Comment: Oh thank you. I didn't know that.

Comment: So is it possible that sysread can't read because the terminal blocks it because of writing its mouse tracking data to the standard output?

Comment: Or the terminal simply blocks my software from execution because of a lack of resources when transferring its mouse tracking data to standard input?

Comment: It can be a number of root-causes. You could be resource0starved (i.e. your computer is doing too many things in parallel, resulting in your ruby process not getting enough CPU time), it could be that your clock is unstable (which is very common in virtualized environments) resulting in inaccurate time keeping, it could be your writer is too slow as said earlier, or it could be any number of additional issues. One thing is for sure however: it's not a general problem in Ruby that reads are slow.

Comment: Please don't use "Edit" or "Update" tags in your text. Instead, incorporate the changes into it as if you'd written them initially. We can easily find what changed if we need to since SO provides change control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably something odd in your benchmarking setup. What comes to mind first is that your sender might not write fast enough.

The following benchmark (using [benchmark-ips](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips)) resulted in approximately one read every 1.3 micro-seconds on my 4-years-old Macbook on Ruby 2.2.5.

This benchmark contains additional code to verify that we are reading exactly 1000-character strings. This makes the benchmark almost 50% slower, but still *much* faster than you claim.

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

sysread_1k_strings = 0
read_1k_strings = 0

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  input = ''

  x.warmup = 0

  x.report('sysread') {
    STDIN.sysread(1000, input)
    sysread_1k_strings += 1 if input.length == 1000
  }

  x.report('read') {
    STDIN.read(1000, input)
    read_1k_strings += 1 if input.length == 1000
  }

end

puts "Comparison --------------------------------------"
puts "sysread".rjust(20) + "#{sysread_1k_strings.to_s.rjust(11)} 1000 byte strings read"
puts "read".rjust(20) + "#{read_1k_strings.to_s.rjust(11)} 1000 byte strings read"
```

When reading from `/dev/zero` this resulted in the following benchmark result:

```
$ ruby benchmark.rb < /dev/zero
Warming up --------------------------------------
             sysread     1.000  i/100ms
                read     1.000  i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
             sysread    210.517k (±13.5%) i/s -    915.780k in   4.529414s
                read    475.210k (±10.4%) i/s -      1.956M in   4.209967s
Comparison --------------------------------------
             sysread     915780 1000 byte strings read
                read    1955737 1000 byte strings read
```

Comment: Are there input strings with more than 100 characters in your answer code?

Comment: Thank you for code and explanation. What about reading mouse tracking data from terminal? Why is it slower in that case?

Comment: Sorry, the problem seems to be elsewhere, as you said. Thank you again.